Managing an API route map with use-immer and promises
I am working on a solution to the nextJS double hook calls in dev mode.  I've got some server API calls that cannot handle duplicate calls (I.E. create a row in a DB table gets duplicate entries).  I have decided to go with fix #4 in this article and create a custom fetcher.
https://plainenglish.io/blog/react-18-useeffect-double-call-for-apis-emergency-fix-724b7ee6a646
I'm now running into a conflict between my reducer dispatch function and api calls, which I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.  I'll paraphrase the problem in the code below.
component.js
import { useImmerReducer } from 'use-immer'; //https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-immer
import dashboardReducer from './dashboardReducer.js'

export default function MyDashboard({}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(dashboardReducer,{
    fetchMap: {},
    tableRows: [],
  }
  const handleAddRow = (value) => {
    dispatch({type:'addRow', data:value});
  }
  const getRows = () => {
    dispatch({type:'getRows'});
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={()=>handleAddRow('banana')}>peel</button>
      state.tableRows.map((banana) => <p>{banana}</p>);
    </>
  )
}


dashboardReducer.js
import {createFetch,deleteFetch} from './fetcher.js'

export function dashboardReducer(draft,action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'getRows': {
      createFetch(draft.fetcher,'api/getRows',{
        /*options for an http request.*/
      }).then((res) => { //THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
        draft.tableRows = res.json() //what I want to do, details missing.
        deleteFetch(draft.fetchMap,'/api/getRows');
      });
      break;
    }
    case 'addRow': {
      draft.tableRows.push(action.data);
      createFetch(draft.fetcher,'/api/addRow',{
        /*options for an http request.*/
      }).then((res) => { //THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
        deleteFetch(draft.fetchMap,'/api/getRows');
      });
      break;
    }
  }

}


fetcher.js
export function createFetch(fetchMap,url,options) { //cs=client session
    if (!fetchMap[url]) {
        fetchMap[url] = fetch(url,options).then((res) => res.json());
    }
    return fetchMap[url];
}
export function deleteFetch(fetchMap,url) {
    delete fetchMap[url]
}

Apologies for typos in the code above, I typed it fresh, so there might be parenthesis mistakes.
Anyway, I have two comments '//THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK' which point out where I am afraid I might have painted myself in a corner.  I'm not sure how to scope the then() function to get the proper state object.  I'm not sure if there even is a way to do this using immer and reducer functions?
I currently have a working set of code, but I handle mutations to the state with the reducer, and handle fetcher related issues with useState(), and this works...HOWEVER...this makes the code very confusing, and defeats the purpose of using the reducer in the first place.
Additionally, the actual code uses much more complicated function calls to handle a much more intricate state object.  Being able to somehow wrap the custom fetcher into the reducer function would be a big win to keep this code manageable.  So the bottom line question is: Is there a proper way to get the '.then()' call to act on the correct state, so the fetchMap cleans out when the api call promise resolves within the dispatcher call?

It seems you have at least a couple issues going on in your code.

Reducers should be pure synchronous functions. This means they should not make asynchronous side-effects like fetch requests.
You appear to unnecessarily couple data fetching to state management.

Without going down the rabbit hole of implementing a full-blown query-caching-request-system I suggest just encapsulating the data fetching and "in-flight" requests in a custom React hook separate from the useImmerReducer hook that should only concern itself with state updates.
Example:
const fetchMap = {};

export const useFetcher = () => {
  const createFetch = (url, options) => {
    if (!fetchMap[url]) {
      fetchMap[url] = fetch(url, options)
        .then((res) => res.json());
    }
    return fetchMap[url];
  };

  const deleteFetch = (url) => {
    delete fetchMap[url];
  };

  return { createFetch, deleteFetch };
};

Update the reducer function to just process state updates
export function dashboardReducer(draft, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'getRows': {
      draft.tableRows = action.payload;
      break;
    }

    case 'addRow': {
      draft.tableRows.push(action.payload);
      break;
    }
  }
}

import { useImmerReducer } from 'use-immer'; 
import dashboardReducer from './dashboardReducer.js';
import { useFetcher } from '../path/to/useFetcher';

export default function MyDashboard() {
  const { createFetch, deleteFetch } = useFetcher();

  const [state, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(
    dashboardReducer,
    { tableRows: [] },
  );

  const handleAddRow = async (value) => {
    try {
      createFetch('/api/addRow', { /* options */ });
      dispatch({ type:'addRow', payload: value });
    } catch(error) {
      // handle/ignore
    } finally {
      deleteFetch('/api/getRows');
    }
  };

  const getRows = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await createFetch('api/getRows', { /* options */ });
      dispatch({ type: 'getRows', payload: data });
    } catch(error) {
      // handle/ignore
    } finally {
      deleteFetch('/api/getRows');
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => handleAddRow('banana')}>
        peel
      </button>
      {state.tableRows.map((banana) => <p>{banana}</p>)}
    </>
  )
}


Thank you very much for your help!  I think I have a good way forward now.  I really needed some input to get out of my head!
